# Dash Figure not JSON Serialiable

Tags: python-3.x, plotly-dash

I'm trying to update a histogram in Dash through a list of filters by setting the figure property as an output, but it's not updating and instead giving an error that the returned Figure object is not JSON serializable. I've tried several different Figure objects including some of their examples on their docs, but it's still giving me the error that it's not JSON serializable.

```
@app.callback(
    Output("graph", "figure"),
    Input({"type": "key", "index": ALL}, "value"),
)
def apply_filters(val):
    dat = px.data.iris()
    figure = px.scatter(dat, x='sepal_width', y='sepal_length', color='species', title='A Plotly Express Figure')
    return figure
```

I get the following error

```
dash.exceptions.InvalidCallbackReturnValue: The callback for `[<Output `graph.figure`>]`
returned a value having type `Figure`
which is not JSON serializable.


The value in question is either the only value returned,
or is in the top level of the returned list,

and has string representation
`Figure({
'data': [{'hovertemplate': 'species=setosa<br>sepal_width=%{x}<br>sepal_length=%{y}<extra></extra>',
'legendgroup': 'setosa',
'marker': {'color': '#636efa', 'symbol': 'circle'},
'mode': 'markers',
'name': 'setosa',
'orientation': 'v',
'showlegend': True,
'type': 'scatter',
'x': array([3.5, 3. , 3.2, 3.1, 3.6, 3.9, 3.4, 3.4, 2.9, 3.1, 3.7, 3.4, 3. , 3. ,
4. , 4.4, 3.9, 3.5, 3.8, 3.8, 3.4, 3.7, 3.6, 3.3, 3.4, 3. , 3.4, 3.5,
3.4, 3.2, 3.1, 3.4, 4.1, 4.2, 3.1, 3.2, 3.5, 3.1, 3. , 3.4, 3.5, 2.3,
3.2, 3.5, 3.8, 3. , 3.8, 3.2, 3.7, 3.3]),
'xaxis': 'x',
'y': array([5.1, 4.9, 4.7, 4.6, 5. , 5.4, 4.6, 5. , 4.4, 4.9, 5.4, 4.8, 4.8, 4.3,
5.8, 5.7, 5.4, 5.1, 5.7, 5.1, 5.4, 5.1, 4.6, 5.1, 4.8, 5. , 5. , 5.2,
5.2, 4.7, 4.8, 5.4, 5.2, 5.5, 4.9, 5. , 5.5, 4.9, 4.4, 5.1, 5. , 4.5,
4.4, 5. , 5.1, 4.8, 5.1, 4.6, 5.3, 5. ]),
'yaxis': 'y'},
{'hovertemplate': 'species=versicolor<br>sepal_width=%{x}<br>sepal_length=%{y}<extra></extra>',
'legendgroup': 'versicolor',
'marker': {'color': '#EF553B', 'symbol': 'circle'},
'mode': 'markers',
'name': 'versicolor',
'orientation': 'v',
'showlegend': True,
'type': 'scatter',
'x': array([3.2, 3.2, 3.1, 2.3, 2.8, 2.8, 3.3, 2.4, 2.9, 2.7, 2. , 3. , 2.2, 2.9,
2.9, 3.1, 3. , 2.7, 2.2, 2.5, 3.2, 2.8, 2.5, 2.8, 2.9, 3. , 2.8, 3. ,
2.9, 2.6, 2.4, 2.4, 2.7, 2.7, 3. , 3.4, 3.1, 2.3, 3. , 2.5, 2.6, 3. ,
2.6, 2.3, 2.7, 3. , 2.9, 2.9, 2.5, 2.8]),
'xaxis': 'x',
'y': array([7. , 6.4, 6.9, 5.5, 6.5, 5.7, 6.3, 4.9, 6.6, 5.2, 5. , 5.9, 6. , 6.1,
5.6, 6.7, 5.6, 5.8, 6.2, 5.6, 5.9, 6.1, 6.3, 6.1, 6.4, 6.6, 6.8, 6.7,
6. , 5.7, 5.5, 5.5, 5.8, 6. , 5.4, 6. , 6.7, 6.3, 5.6, 5.5, 5.5, 6.1,
5.8, 5. , 5.6, 5.7, 5.7, 6.2, 5.1, 5.7]),
'yaxis': 'y'},
{'hovertemplate': 'species=virginica<br>sepal_width=%{x}<br>sepal_length=%{y}<extra></extra>',
'legendgroup': 'virginica',
'marker': {'color': '#00cc96', 'symbol': 'circle'},
'mode': 'markers',
'name': 'virginica',
'orientation': 'v',
'showlegend': True,
'type': 'scatter',
'x': array([3.3, 2.7, 3. , 2.9, 3. , 3. , 2.5, 2.9, 2.5, 3.6, 3.2, 2.7, 3. , 2.5,
2.8, 3.2, 3. , 3.8, 2.6, 2.2, 3.2, 2.8, 2.8, 2.7, 3.3, 3.2, 2.8, 3. ,
2.8, 3. , 2.8, 3.8, 2.8, 2.8, 2.6, 3. , 3.4, 3.1, 3. , 3.1, 3.1, 3.1,
2.7, 3.2, 3.3, 3. , 2.5, 3. , 3.4, 3. ]),
'xaxis': 'x',
'y': array([6.3, 5.8, 7.1, 6.3, 6.5, 7.6, 4.9, 7.3, 6.7, 7.2, 6.5, 6.4, 6.8, 5.7,
5.8, 6.4, 6.5, 7.7, 7.7, 6. , 6.9, 5.6, 7.7, 6.3, 6.7, 7.2, 6.2, 6.1,
6.4, 7.2, 7.4, 7.9, 6.4, 6.3, 6.1, 7.7, 6.3, 6.4, 6. , 6.9, 6.7, 6.9,
5.8, 6.8, 6.7, 6.7, 6.3, 6.5, 6.2, 5.9]),
'yaxis': 'y'}],
'layout': {'legend': {'title': {'text': 'species'}, 'tracegroupgap': 0},
'template': '...',
'title': {'text': 'A Plotly Express Figure'},
'xaxis': {'anchor': 'y', 'domain': [0.0, 1.0], 'title': {'text': 'sepal_width'}},
'yaxis': {'anchor': 'x', 'domain': [0.0, 1.0], 'title': {'text': 'sepal_length'}}}
})`

In general, Dash properties can only be
dash components, strings, dictionaries, numbers, None,
or lists of those.
```

I also tried to instead update the children of a parent div with

```
@app.callback(
    Output("graph-container", "children"),
    Input({"type": "key", "index": ALL}, "value"),
)
def apply_filters(val):
    dat = px.data.iris()
    figure = px.scatter(dat, x='sepal_width', y='sepal_length', color='species', title='A Plotly Express Figure')
    graph = dcc.Graph(
        figure = figure
    )
    return graph
```

which gave the error `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'component_property'` (not sure why this is).
When I wrapped the `dcc.Graph` in a list, it once again gives the error that a returned value having type 'List' is not JSON serializable. Any idea how to fix this problem?
I'm also confused because I have another function that adds to the children list of a div for adding more filters, and that component/callback had no problems even though it was also returning a children list. Does it have something to do with the `dcc.Graph` component and something special I should do with that?